# Superposition theorem for transient analysis

Tags: transient, circuits

Can we apply superposition theorem in transient analysis of circuits? I don't think it can be used since during transient state the input and output relation is not linear and is rather explained by exponential functions like in case of RL and RC circuits. Please consider a case having two different sources with different frequencies.

Comment: Yes, superposition can be used for transient analysis if the system is linear. Why is the input/output relationship non-linear? What non-linear components are in the circuit? 'Linear', in the systems sense, does not mean that the signals are related by a linear graph.

Comment: @Chu I mean to say that Q and V are defined by exponential functions not linear in RC Circuits when we do DC Analysis.

Comment: @Chu, can you illustrate with an example.

Comment: Read about the conditions for linearity - there are a number, but as an illustration of one of them: for a linear system, if you apply a step input, \$\small x(t)\$, and get an exponential response, \$\small y(t)\$, and then apply, \$\small Kx(t)\$ where  \$\small K\$ is a constant, the response will be \$\small Ky(t)\$.

Comment: ... also, for a linear system, if you apply  \$\small x_1(t)\$ to give  \$\small y_1(t)\$; and apply \$\small x_2(t)\$ to give \$\small y_2(t)\$; then, applying \$\small (x_1(t)+ x_2(t))\$ will give \$\small (y_1(t)+ y_2(t))\$. From this you can see, for example, that any circuit that includes a diode is (potentially) non-linear.

Comment: ...also interesting to note that, from the systems definition of linearity, \$\small y=mx+c\$ is not a linear relationship. It is, of course, linear from the algebraic perspective.

Comment: Why it is not linear?

Comment: From a systems definition, say you have \$\small y=2x+3\$. Then, \$\small x=1\$ gives \$\small y=5\$, and \$\small x=2\$ gives \$\small y=7\$. Clearly, doubling \$\small x\$ does not double \$\small y\$. Also \$\small x=1+2=3\$ does not give \$\small y= 5+7=12\$

Comment: @JohnCena I like Grant Sanderson's [essence of linear algebra](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab) series as a segue on linear systems. For a transient response example involving all those functions you hinted towards, you might look over some of: [source-free, under-damped, parallel RLC with 2 initial conditions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/373393/38098).

Comment: Is Gilbert Strang's Series of MIT Lectures in Linear Algebra also good?

Comment: The equation \$y=2x+3\$ is not linear because it does not satisfy the principle of additivity and proportionality. You can find more details here: http://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202013.pdf

Comment: Yes, Gilbert Strang's lectures are excellent.