# Find the expression for \$Vc\$

Tags: circuit-analysis

Given this circuit
[image]

Switch \$S\$ is closed for a long time (\$t<0\$). At \$t=0\$, switch \$S\$ is opened. Find expression for \$V_c\$.

I know if the circuit only has one source I could apply KCL right away. But in this case, the circuit has two sources.

Comment: A little hint is to realise that when the switch has been closed for a long time the capacitor will be fully charged to a fixed voltage. Therefore there is only running a current in the left loop and no current in the right loop. And then try to  think off what an inductor looks like after infinite time :)

Comment: @JakobHalskov The inductor will act as a short circuit. Just making sure my work is on the right track, \$V_C(0) = -22 V\$, is it?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: And as a follow up: the circuit will only have one source when the switch is opened at t=0

Comment: @JakobHalskov You are correct that the capacitor will have -22 V across it at t=0. But also, there will be 2 A through the inductor at this time. So you have two initial conditions: the current in the inductor and the voltage across the capacitor. The entire circuit is a series arrangement of an R, an L and a C between +24 V and ground, with two known initial conditions. For a slightly different analysis [see here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/373393/38098).

Comment: @jonk how about \$i(0)\$? is it 2A or 0A, and why?