# Transient analysis of parallel RLC circuit

Tags: capacitor, inductor, transient, network

Here, I am solving this circuit where Capacitor acts as a voltage source of 10 V. Switch is closed at t=0,and Vc(0-)=10V,I2(0-)=0. When t≥0, what will be the time constant and frequency of the circuit?From my calculation,A=10 and A=B*omega. But how to calculate B? Is omega the angular frequency equal to resonant frequency?I have written the kvl equation I1(t)=dI2/dt Or, Ae^(-kt)cos(wt)=Be^(-kt)wcos(wt)+kBe^(-kt)sin(wt)
When t=0, A=Bw and
Vc(0-)=10V, hence Vc(t)=10e^(-kt)cos(wt)=I1(t)
But what is k and w for parallel RLC circuit?  I also got the equation, I1(t)+I2(t)= -dVc(t)/dt
Or,Ae^(-kt)cos(wt)+Be^(-kt)sin(wt)=Ae^(-kt)wsin(wt)-Ake^(-kt)cos(wt)
By solving it, k= (-1)  and B=Aw
Correct me if I am wrong.

[image]

Comment: To get help with homework questions there is a minimum standard, basically you have to show your work so people can see where you're going wrong and help you.

Comment: Hint \$v_L(t)=v_C(t)=v_R(t)\$

Comment: I have written the kvl equation
I1(t)=dI2/dt
Or, Ae^(-kt)cos(wt)=Be^(-kt)wcos(wt)+kBe^(-kt)sin(wt)

Comment: @Camila'svoice Whatever you did you need to add to your question, not in the comments. But, if that's all you did, chances are nobody's going to answer.

Comment: When t=0, A=Bw and as Vc(0-)=10V ,Vc(t)=10e^(-kt)cos(wt) but what's k and w?

Comment: Is w=1/√(LC).   ?

Comment: @Camila'svoice You night also look at [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/373393/38098). I should probably improve it. But at least it covers the details.

Comment: I got it...thank you